On parole in one state but then get arrested in a different state
What happens if you are on parole in one state for a DWI but then get arrested for assault in a different state. Will the other state find out and take away your parole?

All states are not the same, but generally you need permission to leave the state and must transfer your parole to the new state if it will be more than a short trip.
Pretty much all states are now electronically connected, and the new state will learn of your parole status almost immediately if you are arrested.  There are options to transfer parole, but only a lawyer will be able to determine how best to proceed.  Revocation of parole must be done via a hearing, which qualifies for a public defender.

To people outside the USA it sounds very strange that someone could not move freely in the country (USA). Not being able to leave the USA makes sense. But in Germany, UK, France etc. you can move anywhere in the country unless you have really strong restrictions, like staying at the same address.

@gnasher729 this is a result if the state-federal complexities of the US, which is literally a set of united states.  I suggest it is similar to the UK, tho most things the UK countries are responsible for were assigned by the central government, versus retained by US states.

@gnasher729 : Each state has its own criminal code. Most instances of murder, rape, theft, burglary, robbery, kidnapping, are offenses against the laws of a particular state rather than of the U.S.A., and a parole board would have jurisdiction only within the particular state.

@TigerGuy other similar systems include Canada, Australia, Germany, and Switzerland, but I believe in all of those countries the criminal code is established at the federal level.  I believe enforcement in those cases is mostly at the provincial/state/cantonal level, i.e., the trial happens in a court controlled by the constituent entity rather than the federal government, but I don't really know.  In the UK you have the odd situation of crimes defined by the Westminster parliament that in some cases apply only in a subset of the three subsidiary legal systems.
